# Using ON DELETE CASCADE without updating foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have to delete data in multiple table with foreign key relation. I can easily do it with `ON DELETE CASCADE` rule in my foreign key definition but I do not want to do that. I just want to create a query that can perform an `ON DELETE CASCADE` capability without updating my `FK` but I do not have ant idea how.

I tried creating multiple delete statement, one for each table but that seemed to be too hassle.

What is the easiest way to delete data from a multiple table with FK relationship?

Comment: Read about [Triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Answer (score 1):

While `on delete cascade` is the prefered way to do this, you can also do this with a single [`delete`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html) query, since it supports deletion from multiple tables. If you can properly join your tables (which you trivially should be able to do via their foreign key relations), you can delete from them at once:

> You can specify multiple tables in a DELETE statement to delete rows from one or more tables depending on the condition in the WHERE clause. [...], only matching rows from the tables listed before the FROM clause are deleted.

So you can use for example:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent (id)
);

INSERT INTO parent(id) VALUES (1), (2), (3);
INSERT INTO child(id, parent_id) VALUES (1,1), (2,1), (3,2), (4,2), (5,3), (6,3);

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

DELETE child, parent 
FROM child
JOIN parent ON child.parent_id = parent.id 
WHERE parent.id = 1;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

You have very little control over the deletion order, and in almost every case, MySQL will prefer an execution order that would violate the foreign key constraints (since that is probably the only viable way to join your tables), so for this to work you will need to disable [FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) temporarily; see also the remark in [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html):

> If you use a multiple-table DELETE statement involving InnoDB tables for which there are foreign key constraints, the MySQL optimizer might process tables in an order that differs from that of their parent/child relationship. In this case, the statement fails and rolls back. Instead, you should delete from a single table and rely on the ON DELETE capabilities that InnoDB provides to cause the other tables to be modified accordingly.